# What type of Azure App service to host net core console application?

Tags: azure, .net-core, long-polling, azure-web-app-service

I have a long running console application, using while(true)...  structure
 It implemented by using Net Core
What type of Azure App Service I should create to host that application ?

Comment: just to mention that Azure Pipelines too can be used to run console apps: https://devsdaily.com/azure-devops-how-to-run-console-applications-on-azure-pipeline/

Answer (score 7):

[Decision tree for Azure compute services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree)

Azure offers a number of ways to host your application code. The term compute refers to the hosting model for the computing resources that your application runs on. The following flowchart will help you to choose a compute service for your application. The flowchart guides you through a set of key decision criteria to reach a recommendation.

Treat this flowchart as a starting point. Every application has unique requirements, so use the recommendation as a starting point. Then perform a more detailed evaluation, looking at aspects such as:

- Feature set
- Service limits
- Cost
- SLA
- Regional availability
- Developer ecosystem and team skills
- Compute comparison tables

I recommend reading this guide afterwards

- [Criteria for choosing an Azure compute service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-comparison)

Another great entry point for developers concerned with a similar question

- [.NET application architecture](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/architecture)

Comment: Nice decision tree - I hadn't seen that before.

Comment: My expected is a simple answer, the name of feature help me host long running application

Comment: @phuongnd you did not tell that much about your application - especially about your system context. I could have asked for more details but I saw value in guiding you towards a learning path eventually helping you make an informed decision yourself.

Answer (score 5):

> You have to use "Azure App Service as a WebJob"

To deploy the .NET Core console application to an Azure App Service Web App Web Job access the Azure portal and navigate to the Azure App Service where you will host the WebJob.

[image]

Clicking on the Add button renders the blade

[image]

Once the WebJob is successfuly uploaded, it will render in the WebJob blade.  Click on it and you will see the Run button.  As this WebJob is a manually triggered job, you must click on the Run button in order for the job logic within the .NET Core console application to run.

[image]

After starting the .NET Core WebJob, click on the Logs link and a new browser tab is opened and you can see the most current state of the WebJob
[image]

Comment: Hi @thennarasan, under my App Service, the web job menu is gray out, and display: This feature is not supported for your current plan

Comment: Do you have Function App enabled?

Comment: Yes, I can create Function App. Your mean is create Function App instead AppService-WebApp ?

Comment: Yes.. Either you can use as web job or you can use Function App and do the same implementation.

Comment: In my mind, Function App is need something like trigger to run function, but my application is long running, how about that?

Comment: Yep.. since you code contains the while condition it going to run until the condition is statisfied.. make sure you trigger back when it has to start again.

Comment: Yes, It seem to hard to keep allow only one instance of application run at same time.